# Is there any relation between class cluster and generics?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Is there any relation between class cluster and generics ?

So i was reading about class cluster pattern and it sounds like there is some similarity between class cluster pattern and generics.

Comment: Do you have some links where you read this and maybe let us know which parts made you believe there is a relation between the two? What do you even consider as relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't very similar. [Class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html) is a pattern for **providing multiple implementations** of the same abstract data structure, without exposing this detail to the library user.
For example there are many different ways to implement `NSDictionary`. Should it use a hash table? Linked list chaining? A tree? Just a linear searched array? There are several subclasses of `NSDictionary` that implement a few of these options. When you create an `NSDictionary`, it uses the parameters given to pick one of these subclasses to create. It is returned to you as an `NSDictionary` so you can use it without worrying about the underlying implementation.

Generics on the other hand provide a way to **reuse the same implementation** for several types. The basic example being `Array<int>`. The same array implementation can be given different types instead of int and they will work similarly.
Unlike class clusters, this actually doesn't change the underlying behavior of the class, other than substituting in a type.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not the case because
**class clusters** is a *design pattern* while **generics** is a *language feature*.

---

Some more info at hand:

> **[Class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html)**
>
> A class cluster is an architecture that groups a number of private,
>   concrete subclasses under a public, abstract superclass.

---

> **[Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html)**
>
> ...
>
> Generics are one of the most powerful features of Swift, and much
>   of the  Swift standard library is built with generic code.